# A topic with the name,XXX already exists. How to mass rename a Topic to an already existing one?

Tags: topics, duplicate-value

I have a problem / question.

There are a large number of topics in salesforce with the wrong format.
Example: Topic_1= TEST_123, Topic_2=TEST 123 - I have many such examples.

I do not want topics with a space. However, when I want to change the name of a Topic I get an error: "A topic with the name,TEST 123, already exists. DUPLICATE_VALUE.
Do you know how to mass rename a Topic to an already existing one?

Deleting topics and adding new ones is out, because I will lose the date of creating deleted topics from previous years. New topics will have today's creation date.

Thank you for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the Topic itself. You need to interact with the assignment of the topic which means you have to essentially delete the wrong association and create a new association for the same records to the correct Topic.

This is stored in the [TopicAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_topicassignment.htm) object which is not updateable (hence, you have to delete and create). You can query/export with dataloader the Ids of the "wrong" topic

```
//Existing Topic Associations that are to the wrong topic
SELECT Id,EntityId FROM TopicAssignment WHERE Topic.Name = 'TEST 123'
```

Afterwards, create a TopicAssignment record for all the same records by setting the `EntityId` and `TopicId`.

It can be done with dataloader as well.

1. Export the wrong assignments (similar to query above). Make sure to select "show all Salesforce objects" to see TopicAssignment
2. Delete using excel from export
3. Figure out the TopicId of the right topic and update the value in TopicId in the excel next to all the EntityIds (records)
4. Run an insert with the TopicId and EntityId as the columns.

Your records should now be correctly associated to the topic you'd like. You can safely delete the wrong topic.